# javaのzip4jでパスワード付きのzipファイルを作りたい

Tags: java

javaでパスワード付きのzipファイルを作ろうとしています
引数は以下の通り

1. 出力するzipのファイルパス
2. パスワード
3. zipファイルに入れるフォルダパス

実行した結果、引数「1.」に記述したパスにzipファイルは出来上がったものの、パスワードが付いていませんでした…
解凍すると引数「3.」のフォルダが入っており、そのフォルダの中身も元フォルダと同じです
また、引数「3.」のフォルダの中身は、ファイルとフォルダが混同しています
どうすればパスワード付きのzipになるのか教えていただきたいです

以下、ソースコードと参考にしたサイトです

```
package zip_with_password;

import java.io.File;

import net.lingala.zip4j.ZipFile;
import net.lingala.zip4j.model.ZipParameters;
import net.lingala.zip4j.model.enums.EncryptionMethod;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // 圧縮用パラメーター
        ZipParameters zipParameters = new ZipParameters();
        zipParameters.setEncryptFiles(true);
        zipParameters.setEncryptionMethod(EncryptionMethod.ZIP_STANDARD);
         
        try {
            String outputPath = args[0];
            String password = args[1];
            System.out.println("get outputPath : " + outputPath); // debug
            System.out.println("get password : " + password); // debug
         
            // ZipFileインスタンスを生成します。
            // コンストラクタの引数に、"出力先" と "パスワード" を指定します。
            @SuppressWarnings("resource")
            ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(outputPath, password.toCharArray());
            // 圧縮するファイルをパスで指定
            String inputPath = args[2];
            System.out.println("get inputPath : " + inputPath); // debug
            File folder = new File(inputPath);
            zipFile.addFolder(folder, zipParameters);                       
                
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // 例外処理
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        System.out.println("end"); // debug
    }

}
```

参考：
https://kita-note.com/java-password-protected-zip-zip4j

よろしくお願いします

Answer (score 0):

記載されているコードを実行してみましたが、想定通りの挙動になっているように見えます。
なお、ファイル名(などディレクトリ構造)が見えるのは ZIP の仕様です。

[.ZIP File Format Specification 6.2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_(file_format)#Encryption) でファイル名の暗号化も仕様化されたそうですが、 zip4j は対応していないようです([参考](https://github.com/srikanth-lingala/zip4j/issues/163))。